# Удаление дубликатов из словаря python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишу программу для удаления дубликатов из словаря.
Например, для следующего словаря:

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 'test': 1}
```

Вывод программы должен быть следующим:

```
d = {1: 1, 3: 2}
```

Мой код:

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 'test': 1}
d = {d[item] for item in d}
print(d)
```

Получаю {1,2}

Мои уникальные значения становятся ключами. Помогите разобраться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 'test': 1}
v_by_k = dict()
for k, v in d.items():
    if v not in v_by_k:
        v_by_k[v] = k

new_d = {v: k for k, v in v_by_k.items()}
print(new_d)
# {1: 1, 3: 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 'test': 1}
res = {}
[res.update({k:v}) for k,v in d.items() if v not in res.values()]
```

res: {1: 1, 3: 2}

Comment: Чем лучше? в этом случае будет то же решение от gil9red, но через генераторы. а здесь важно было показать метод update.

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 'test': 1}

values = set()
new_d = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    if v not in values:
        new_d.update({k: v})
        values.add(v)
```

результат в `new_d`:

```
new_d
{1: 1, 3: 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Однострочник:

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 'test': 1}

print({v:k for k,v in {d[k]:k for k in reversed(list(d))}.items()})
```

Вывод:

```
{1: 1, 3: 2}
```

Суть: меняю местами ключи и значения, перебирая словарь в обратном порядке (чтобы первые элементы затёрли последние), а потом меняю ключи и значения местами ещё раз.

Comment: с какой то версии, словарь работает с `reversed` и поэтому брать просто ключи не обязательно

Comment: @Danis В колабе ругается: `TypeError: 'dict' object is not reversible`, но там конечно не последняя версия

Comment: Это работает начинаю с Python 3.8. Но все таки лучше использовать как у вас, так будет универсальней

Comment: @Danis Не, как у меня - это чисто для ума упражнение, использовать лучше другие решения ))

Comment: я имел ввиду `reversed(list(d))`. Данный вариант будет работать на всех версиях, а `reversed(d)` только на 3.8+

Comment: @Danis А, понял. Торможу-с )

Answer (score -2):

А можно вообще не заморачиватся и вспомнить о том что в питоне есть несколько типов данных один из которых множества. Так вот в множестве не бывает дублей ))

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 'test': 1}

new_d = set(d)
```

Получаем список уникальных значений без циклов и прочего питон сам уже всё сделал за нас )

Comment: "получаем список уникальных значений"... really? ;)

Comment: мы получим только уникальные ключи

Comment: которые в словаре уже уникальны